# SQLalchemy: how to patch session from context manager and replace with in memory DB session

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, mocking, python-unittest

Say I have an SQLalchemy model like:

```
from app.data_structures.base import (
    Base

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    user_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, nullable=True)
    flag = Column(Boolean)

    def __init__(
        self,
        user_name: str = None,
        flag: bool = false(),
)-> None:
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.flag = flag
```

where app.data_structures.base.py:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from os import environ
from os.path import join, realpath

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Table, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, scoped_session, sessionmaker


db_name = environ.get("DB_NAME")
ROOT_DIR =environ.get("ROOT_DIR")
db_path = realpath(join(ROOT_DIR, "data", db_name))
engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///{db_path}", connect_args={"timeout": 120})
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sql_session = scoped_session(session_factory)


@contextmanager
def Session():
    session = sql_session()

    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception:
        session.rollback()
        raise
```

I then have a function defined (app.helpers.db_helper.get_users_to_query), elsewhere that does something like:

```
from app.data_structures.base import Session
def get_usernames_to_query(flag: bool = False) -> List[User]:
    logger = getLogger(__name__)
    try:
        with Session() as session:
            usernames_to_query = [
                {"user_name": user.user_name}
                for user in session.query(User).filter(
                    User.flag == flag
                )
            ]
    except Exception as err:
        logger.exception(f"Exception thrown in get_users_to_query {' '.join(err.args)}")
        usernames_to_query = []

    return usernames_to_query
```

I am trying to unit test this function, by having a separate session in memory, rather than using the production DB.

I patch the Session() context manager where the function imports it, and then mock the `__enter__` return value to be the in memory session:

```
@patch("app.helpers.db_helper.Session")  
def test_get_users_to_query(self, mock_session) -> None:

       
        self.engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
        self.session = Session(self.engine)
        print(type(mock_session))
        print("session id", id(self.session))

        mock_session.__enter__ = Mock(return_value=self.session)
        mock_session.__exit__ = Mock(return_value=None)

        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)


        (patcher, environ_dict, environ_mock_get) = self.environ_mock_get_factory()

        with patcher():


            fake_user1 = User(
                display_name="Jane Doe", user_name="jdb1", flag=False
            )
            fake_user2 = User(
                display_name="John Doe", user_name="jdb2", flag=True
            )

            with mock_session as session:
                session.add(fake_user1)
                session.add(fake_user2)
                session.commit()

                users = session.query(User).filter(User.flag == True).all()
                print([user.user_name for user in users])

                print(id(session), type(session))

            users_to_query = get_users_to_query()
            print("Users:", users_to_query)
```

In the test above the mocked_session context manger get replaced with self.session, as I would expect. So `print([user.user_name for user in users])` prints the fake_user2's username as expected.

But in the call to `get_users_to_query` it is not and it doesn't query the in memory DB, and `get_users_to_query` returns an empty list.

Can anyone explain why this is, and how to get the session in `get_users_to_query` to be the mocked session with the in memory DB (i.e. self.session)?

Thanks!

Comment: If the function `get_users_to_query()` is contained in the file `db_helper.py`, I think you have to change `@patch("app.helpers.db_helper.get_users_to_query.Session")` to `@patch("app.helpers.db_helper.Session")`... give me a feedback please.

Comment: Thanks @frankfalse - that was an error on my part.

Comment: With my correction your test works or there was an other problem?

Comment: Yeah - that was just a typo, so it hasnt fixed the problem. I have fixed it however solution is in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77022966/factory-session-to-mock-context-manager-doesnt-work